# How to use RE2 to get arbitrary number of captures?

Tags: regex, re2

I'm trying to use RE2 to parse paths formed by an arbitrary number of folders. and I want to break the path apart into folder names

so, if I have "/folderA/folderB", I want to get a list of string ["/folderA", "/folderB"],

My code:

```
RE2 re("(/[a-z0-9]+)+");
if(re.ok()){

    std::cout << "debug: "<<re.NumberOfCapturingGroups()<<std::endl;

};  

RE2::FullMatch("/ggg/uuu", re, &s1);
RE2::FullMatch("/ggg/uuu", re, &s1, &s2); //error,
// because NumberOfCapturingGroups is 1, not infinity,
```

And I can only get "/uuu" with the FullMatch function call. I can't find any examples on how to do this properly?

Other regex libraries would allow accessing to all captures via an index, but I don't find the same functionality in RE2?

Comment: Why not just split on the separator?

Comment: I can, but I feel surprised RE2 can't do it. My main goal is selecting a good regular expression engine for my project, not solving this particular problem. I want a library that matches javascript's or Qt's regular expression engine.